# Replace an image file with a new image

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way to replace an existing image file's image, that exists in the directory?

In a method I have I retrieve what I call "default" images from the app's directory. Now, the app lets the user take images with a custom camera and I want to be able to use the same retrieve method (with the default file names) but with the new images taken with the camera.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

```
@IBAction func show(_ sender: Any) {
    image.image = UIImage(named: "image.jpg")

}

@IBAction func saveImages(_ sender: Any) {
    self.saveImageDocumentDirectory()

}

func saveImageDocumentDirectory() {

    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let paths = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString).appendingPathComponent("image.jpg")
    let image = UIImage(named: "image.jpg")
    print(paths)
    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 0.5)
    fileManager.createFile(atPath: paths as String, contents: imageData, attributes: nil)
}
```

However, I don't know how to retrieve it (if that even is the correct way to save an image to an existing file).

Comment: did you try? and show your code.

Comment: I've added the code!

Comment: You retrieve it by creating the url in the same way as you did to save it. Get the documents directory and append the file name to it.

Comment: Could you please make a little example?

Comment: hi Cukoo, image1.png remain static ?

Comment: https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2016/04/save-and-get-image-from-document.html

Comment: Yes, the image doesn't replace the old image. It fails to save if the name already exists.

Comment: ok now i understood, you want to override image with the same name.

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanna do :/

Comment: so simple when you want to save new image you have to delete old image before saving new image. now understood or i give you code?

Comment: Please show me some code!

Comment: ok wait i am giving. did you try https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2016/04/save-and-get-image-from-document.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func saveImageDocumentDirectory() {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let paths = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString).appendingPathComponent("image.png")
        let image = UIImage(named: "image.png")
        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 0.5)
        fileManager.createFile(atPath: paths as String, contents: imageData, attributes: nil)
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't save it as a new image!

Comment: so you want to replace old image or you want save as newimage?

Comment: I want to replace the old image!

Comment: @Cukoo above code is working for replacing image. I am sure you are doing some mistake.

Comment: paste your all code. what you are doing after getting image from imagepicker.

Comment: I put it in a UIImage called img

Comment: Maybe I'm not retrieving it correctly, because I only try: img = UIImage(named: "image.jpg") and the default image is shown...

Comment: paste all code so i can see, where you are doing mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code on swift 4 and it works when overwriting a file :)

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default 
let path = URL(string: "your file path here")
do {
    let image = UIImage(named: "sampleImage")
    if let imageData = image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5) {
        try imageData.write(to: path, options: Data.WritingOptions.atomic)
    }
} catch {
    //handle error here
}
```